# IBM Worklight v6.0 - Error while adding an application to the Mobile Test Workbench

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I have a Worklight app, created an apk file from it. Created a Test Project.
Adding the apk file to the workbench, it has an error saying:

> Application xxx.apk cannot be imported; it is either an invalid one or
>   it contains specific features that are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

Try opening the .log file for the worklight workspace.  I saw an error saying that for the Rational Test Workbench to work, I need to use JDK and not JRE.

The solution that solves my problem is as follow:

- In the workspace, go to **Window** > **Preferences**
- Expand **Java** > **Installed JREs**
- Add a **new JDK** and ticky mark it
- Open the xxx.ma file
- You should still see the error in that file
- Select the mobile app from the test workbench file.  **Delete** it
- **Add** the mobile app again to the test workbench file.  It will take some time to process.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely to do with the fact that your Eclipse is not pointing to a JDK.
Please edit eclipse.ini to point to your JDK (-vm ... jdk location...)