# Application cannot be imported; it is either an invalid one or it contains specific features that are not supported

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I followed the recommended solution:
[IBM Worklight v6.0 - Error while adding an application to the Mobile Test Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278129/ibm-worklight-v6-0-error-while-adding-an-application-to-the-mobile-test-workbe)

still got the error even though my jdk seems to be already correct

I didn't see any errors in the test workbench mobile client log (emulator), which log should I be looking at?

Comment: You do not mention your Worklight version nor your MTWW version, nor the error (we should not go to another question to see 'it'). Please it'd be great if you could supply a project with your particular setup that we could test.

Comment: It's for Worklight 6.2 and MTWW 8.5.1. Please find the project zip and screenshot at Google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_jz2H1UHy2fRmpwUG5YMzlfMU0&usp=sharing)

Comment: cotton, it'd be nice if you will make that link public. ;)

Comment: Sorry, I just fixed it. Please try again.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you are using Android 4.4 and not Android 4.4W or 4.4L which are not yet supported. And you should have made recently an update of the Android SDK tools to version 23 (you can verify by opening the SDK Manager)

Google has modified in this release the way the tools are organized and this made MTWW regressed when instrumenting. 
There is a workaround: copy <android-sdk-dir>/build-tools/20.0.0/zipalign[.exe] to <android-sdk-dir>/tools.

Dominique

Comment: I copied C:\IBM\android-sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\zipalign.exe to C:\IBM\android-sdk\tools but still got the same error. I've added AndroidManifest.xml and screenshot of SDK Manager to the Google drive. I am using SDK version 19 (Android 4.4.2). I also have the update for Android SDK Tools 23.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. You may need hotfix or uptdate to RTW8.6.

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21678859

Comment: Thank you! The hotfix got rid of the original error. However, now I got java heap space error. I tried modifying -Xms512m -Xmx1024m in eclipse.ini and run eclipse.exe -clean, but still got the error. Please see details in my google drive [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_jz2H1UHy2fRmpwUG5YMzlfMU0&usp=sharing)