# Uploading Native Android Apps fails in MTWW

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-mtww

I'm coming across problems uploading a native android app from the device/emulator to the MTW.  The scenario is this:

1. User builds a mobile app using Android Studio and the CLI
2. Deploys the mobile app to the emulator or device
3. Tests the functionality and it works ok
4. Create a Test Workbench Project in eclipse
5. Launches the MTW Client on the emulator and connects to the Test Workbench Project
6. Uploads the application from the Android emulator to the Test Workbench

It is at this point that it fails and I get an error uploading it.  it seems to be some sort of align problem again but I don't know how to solve it.

**Now If I upload a hybrid Android app, then it works, so I know that my eclipse environment is configured ok (to a certain extent at least) as I got around the initial zipalign problem.**

So my initial thoughts are

1. Maybe there is some additional configuration that I need to do to that is unclear to me
2. Maybe the apk file that I am using is invalid in some way and I need to do something special to be able to upload it
   Note I played around with the zipalign option in the build.gradle file. but to no avail.

   .
   android {
       compileSdkVersion 19
       buildToolsVersion "19.1"

   ```
   defaultConfig {
       minSdkVersion 10
       targetSdkVersion 19
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
   }
   buildTypes {
       release {
           runProguard false
           proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
           zipAlign true
       }
   }
   ```

   }
    ...

The logs show the following

```
!ENTRY com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb 1 0 2014-08-26 21:37:08.540
!MESSAGE CRRTWM6013I from component Android-BuildChain: configuration: {cache.dir=C:\Work\Worklight_v62\Test\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\cache, android.runtime.dir=C:\IBM\WorklightStudio_v62\eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime_1.2.100.v20140603_1426, ibm.jdk.install.dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25, android.sdk.install.dir=C:\Utils\Android\android-sdk, runtime.cache.dir=C:\Work\Worklight_v62\Test\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\builds\runtimes}

!ENTRY com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.util 4 0 2014-08-26 21:37:19.161
!MESSAGE LicenseCheck returned FALSE!

!ENTRY com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb 4 0 2014-08-26 21:37:35.694
!MESSAGE CRRTWM6012E exception thrown from component Android-BuildChain while building from '0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1.apk'
!STACK 0
brut.androlib.AndrolibException: com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.utils.ProcessExec$ProcessExecException: Cannot exec command: [C:\Utils\Android\ANDROI~1\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe, p, --no-crunch, -F, C:\Users\mmalc\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL6016720483897094701.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\cache\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res, -M, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\AndroidManifest.xml]
Exit code: 1
Process output stream:

Process error stream:
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:118: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:327: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:368: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:382: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:389: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values-v14\styles.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:401: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:407: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:429: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:502: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base'.

    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:444)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResourcesFull(Androlib.java:376)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.buildResources(Androlib.java:320)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:237)
    at brut.androlib.Androlib.build(Androlib.java:203)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.build(BuildWrapper.java:213)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.build(AndroidBuildChain.java:289)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$Build.run(BuildChainManager.java:198)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.utils.ProcessExec$ProcessExecException: Cannot exec command: [C:\Utils\Android\ANDROI~1\build-tools\20.0.0\aapt.exe, p, --no-crunch, -F, C:\Users\mmalc\AppData\Local\Temp\APKTOOL6016720483897094701.tmp, -0, arsc, -I, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\cache\apktool\framework\1.apk, -S, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res, -M, C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\AndroidManifest.xml]
Exit code: 1
Process output stream:

Process error stream:
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:9: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'TextAppearance.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:118: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:327: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:368: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:382: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:389: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values-v14\styles.xml:84: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:401: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base.DropDownItem'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:407: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:429: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Base'.
C:\Work\WORKLI~4\Test\METADA~1\PLUGIN~1\COMIBM~1.MOE\builds\C2278B~1\0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1\res\values\styles.xml:502: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base'.

    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.utils.ProcessExec.exec(ProcessExec.java:102)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.utils.ProcessExec.exec(ProcessExec.java:77)
    at brut.androlib.res.AndrolibResources.aaptPackage(AndrolibResources.java:442)
    ... 8 more

!ENTRY com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb 4 0 2014-08-26 21:37:35.704
!MESSAGE CRRTWM6010E exception thrown while building from '0-com.example.ibmbankapp.app-1.apk'
!STACK 0
java.lang.Error: Playback-ready package build/sign/align failed
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.build(AndroidBuildChain.java:290)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$Build.run(BuildChainManager.java:198)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I'm using WL v6.2.0.00-20140801-1709
MTWW v 8.5.100.v20131024_1533

I've also already looked at [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25048552/application-cannot-be-imported-it-is-either-an-invalid-one-or-it-contains-speci/25062231#25062231) regarding the zipalign problem and not had any joy as I don't have Android API 20 - 22 installed

Appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 0):

This issue come from the new Android SDK release 23. Google has modified the location of the zipalign tool :-(

Here is the workaround:

copy *android-sdk-dir*/build-tools/*version*/zipalign[.exe] to *android-sdk-dir*/tools

Dominique

Comment: @Dominique, I don't think it's that as I've already solved that problem and  copied that file into the tools folder. So there must be something else going wrong.