# Error while adding Mobile application to Workspace in IBM MobileFirst Platorm 6.3.0

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, ibm-mobilefirst, rational-test-workbench

I have a MobileFirst hybrid app, created an apk file from it. Created a Test Project.
Adding the apk file to the workbench, it has an error saying:

Application cannot be imported; it is either an invalid one or it contains specific features that are not supported.

Find below the error message and error description in Errorlog:

**CRRTWM6013I from component Android-BuildChain: configuration: {cache.dir=C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\cache, android.runtime.dir=C:\Software_Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime_1.3.150.v20141113_1613, ibm.jdk.install.dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71, android.sdk.install.dir=C:\android-sdk-windows, runtime.cache.dir=C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\builds\runtimes}**
    eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
    java.version=1.7.0_71
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

```
com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb
Info
Fri Jan 09 08:45:06 IST 2015
CRRTWM6013I from component Android-BuildChain: configuration: {cache.dir=C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\cache, android.runtime.dir=C:\Software_Eclipse\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.runtime_1.3.150.v20141113_1613, ibm.jdk.install.dir=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_71, android.sdk.install.dir=C:\android-sdk-windows, runtime.cache.dir=C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4\.metadata\.plugins\com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb\builds\runtimes}
```

**LicenseCheck returned FALSE!**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

com.ibm.cic.licensing.common.util
Error
Fri Jan 09 08:45:12 IST 2015
LicenseCheck returned FALSE!
```

**CRRTWM6010E exception thrown while building from 'HelloWorldHelloAndroid.apk'**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.1.M20140925-0400
java.version=1.7.0_71
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -data C:\Users\rakeshm395\workspace4 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb
Error
Fri Jan 09 08:45:23 IST 2015
CRRTWM6010E exception thrown while building from 'HelloWorldHelloAndroid.apk'

java.lang.Error: Cannot find zipalign in C:\ANDROI~2\build-tools\17.0.0
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.alignApk(BuildWrapper.java:316)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.build(BuildWrapper.java:243)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.build(AndroidBuildChain.java:330)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$Build.run(BuildChainManager.java:200)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I have tried the below suggested solutions in StackOverflow but they did not work

[IBM Worklight v6.0 - Error while adding an application to the Mobile Test Workbench](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278129/ibm-worklight-v6-0-error-while-adding-an-application-to-the-mobile-test-workbe)

Answer (score 0):

This is your actual error:

```
java.lang.Error: Cannot find zipalign in C:\ANDROI~2\build-tools\17.0.0
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.alignApk(BuildWrapper.java:316)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.tools.build.BuildWrapper.build(BuildWrapper.java:243)
    at com.ibm.rational.test.mobile.android.buildchain.AndroidBuildChain.build(AndroidBuildChain.java:330)
at com.ibm.rational.test.lt.models.behavior.moeb.utils.BuildChainManager$Build.run(BuildChainManager.java:200)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

1. You should use The Mobile Test Workbench for MobileFirst Platform, not the Rational Test Workbench: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-6-3/advanced-topics/testing-mobilefirst-mobile-applications-mobile-test-workbench/
2. Update your Eclipse Android ADT plug-in
3. Update your Android SDK - update the API levels and SDK build tools
4. Update your MobileFirst project accordingly (the AndroidManifest.xml in the native folder),and the generated Android project (the Build settings) accordingly as well
5. Then try again

Comment: If you've followed them and you get the same error, it means you're still using rational test workbench instead of mobile test workbench per my link.

Comment: Hi Idan. I installed "Android ADT extentions 3.5.1" plugin in eclipse and the error has resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @RakeshManusani, I've updated the answer to include "Update your Android SDK - update the API levels and SDK build tools". This should've solve it. If my answer helped you, please mark as Answered.